# Travis CI shows "Host key verification failed." when I try to clone submodule from Bitbucket

Tags: ios, objective-c, git, xcode6, travis-ci

I have repositories A, B, C and D. A, B and C run on Travis CI. All repositories are located on Github except for D which is located on Bitbucket. D is a sub repository in C. C is a sub repository in A and B. A and B run fine on Travis CI. C however fails. See the output below when Travis CI runs C.

`.travis.yml` specifies build on branch master for all repositories.

I'm not sure what else to try here. It looks like a simple (and I hope it is) SSH authorization denied, but I've verified the public key on Bitbucket as well as the private key on Travis and it matches the keys of A and B (that are running just fine).

**What is the problem here?**

```
Using worker: worker-mac-1.saucelabs.travis-ci.com:travis-mac_osx-19
Installing an SSH key from: repository settings
Key fingerprint: <fingerprint>
$ git clone --depth=50 --branch=master git@github.com:path/to/repo/D.git path/to/repo/D
Cloning into 'path/to/repo/D'...
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.252.129' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
remote: Counting objects: 2005, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1317/1317), done.
remote: Total 2005 (delta 555), reused 1587 (delta 486)
Receiving objects: 100% (2005/2005), 12.95 MiB | 4.64 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (555/555), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
$ cd path/to/repo/C
$ git checkout -qf <SHA-1>
$ git submodule init
Submodule 'path/to/repo/D' (git@bitbucket.org:path/to/repo/D.git) registered for path 'path/to/repo/D'
$ git submodule update
Cloning into 'path/to/repo/D'...
ssh_askpass: exec(/usr/libexec/ssh-askpass): No such file or directory
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Clone of 'git@bitbucket.org:path/to/repo/D.git' into submodule path 'path/to/repo/D' failed
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the host key required for BitBucket isn't available on our build machine, hence the failing host verification.

We can investigate that, but I'd recommend in the meantime to put the required dependency on GitHub to fix this issue, if that's possible.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not possible. :( Why is repo A and B running without problem, they both manage to clone D through C?

Comment: Is repo D a private or a public repository? Is it defined differently in terms of the git URL on A and B, compared to C?

Comment: They are all private repositories. The path is git@bitbucket.org:... The only difference between A,B,C and D is that the prior are on github and the latter on bitbucket.

Comment: Can you email support@travis-ci.com with details so we can have a look? Given that the same setup works with A and B (both including D from what I understand) but not with C, this certainly seems odd.

Comment: Any updates on a solution for this issue? I'm having the same problem

Comment: @KostiantynKoval I honestly can't remember how this went. We later did away with B and D and thus solved the problem.